# I can’t send the desired url to the address bar

Tags: html, django, url, view, model

I need to do so that I can open the news from the main page. But I ran into a problem, the interpreter throws the error "ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'news1' (I add the Traceback and code below). I understand that it expects a number, but receives a string, but I can’t figure out how to fix it Who knows, please help

**Traceback:**

```
Internal Server Error: /news1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1772, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'news1'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\website\views.py", line 18, in get
    posts = Blog.objects.get(id=slug)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 404, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1351, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1378, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1312, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1166, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 72, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\dadi2\Desktop\church\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'news1'.
[09/May/2020 14:10:52] "GET /news1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 132319
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[09/May/2020 14:10:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2430
```

**Views:**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views.generic.base import View

from .models import Blog, Event
# Create your views here.



class EventView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        events = Event.objects.all()
        posts = Blog.objects.all()
        return render(request, "home/home.html", {"events": events, "posts":posts})


class BlogDetailView (View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        posts = Blog.objects.get(id=slug)
        return render(request, "home/blog-detail.html", {"posts": posts})
```

**Models:**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.


class Blog(models.Model):
    """Новости"""
    name = models.CharField("Заголовок", max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    descriptionTwo = models.TextField("Описание (второй абзац)", blank=True, default="")
    blockquote = models.TextField("Цитата", blank=True, default="")
    short = models.TextField("Краткое описание", max_length=300)
    poster = models.ImageField("Изображение", upload_to="news/")
    prewiew = models.ImageField("Превью", upload_to="news/")
    dataPost = models.DateField("Дата публикации", default=date.today)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, blank=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField("Черновик", default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("home_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.url})


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Новости"
        verbose_name_plural = "Новости"


class Event(models.Model):
    """События"""
    name = models.CharField("Заголовок", max_length=100)
    adress = models.TextField("Адрес")
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    short = models.TextField("Краткое описание")
    phone = models.TextField("Контактный номер телефона")
    email = models.EmailField()
    image = models.ImageField("Изображение", upload_to="event/")
    dataStart = models.DateField("Дата старта", default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Событие"
        verbose_name_plural = "События"
```

**Urls:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.EventView.as_view()),
    path("<slug:slug>/", views.BlogDetailView.as_view(), name="home_detail")
```

]

**HTML:**

```
    <!-- Latest-Blog -->
<section class="latest_blog section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="blog">
            <div class="section-header text-center">
                <h2 class="text-capitalize">Новости церкви</h2>
                <p>Здесь вы найдёте самые последние новости из жизни церкви</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                {% if posts %}
                    {% for posts in posts %}
                        <article class="col-md-6 col-12">
                            <div class="blog_wrap">
                                <div class="blog_img">
                                    <a href="{{ posts.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ posts.prewiew.url }}" alt="image"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog_info">
                                    <div class="post_date"><a href="#">{{ posts.dataPost}}</a></div>
                                    <h5><a href="{{ posts.get_absolute_url }}">{{ posts.name }}</a></h5>
                                    <p>{{ posts.short}}</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Details <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    <p>На данный момент новостей нет</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- Latest-Blog -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have defined the href using the `post.url` field in the template

```
<h5><a href="{{ posts.url }}/">{{ posts.name }}</a></h5>
```

so the queryset has to be requested by url slug

```
class BlogDetailView (View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        posts = Blog.objects.get(url=slug)
        return render(request, "home/blog-detail.html", {"posts": posts})
```

Comment: Sorry for being unfulfilled, I didn’t fully understand your answer. Yes changing id to url and this solved the problem. Thanks again